# Serverless cfn resource references not resolving

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm new to serverless, and trying to create a deployment using the Serverless 3 framework. I currently have some resources defined with references to other cfn resources that I've defined in my template, i.e.:

```
  WebsiteBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    DependsOn:
      - CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
      - WebsiteBucket
    Properties:
      Bucket: WebsiteBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join: [ ' ', [ 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity', CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity ] ]
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource:
              - Fn::Join: [ '', [ 'arn:aws:s3:::', WebsiteBucket, '/*' ] ]
```

However, I keep getting cfn errors when I deploy as it seems that the references to these resources aren't resolving. I tried looking at the `serverless-state.json` output file to troubleshoot, and I see them defined as follows, for example:

```
"WebsiteBucketPolicy": {
          "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
          "DependsOn": [
            "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
            "WebsiteBucket"
          ],
          "Properties": {
            "Bucket": "WebsiteBucket",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                    "AWS": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        " ",
                        [
                          "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity",
                          "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity"
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "Action": [
                    "s3:GetObject"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                          "arn:aws:s3:::",
                          "WebsiteBucket",
                          "/*"
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

Am I referencing these incorrectly in my template?

Answer (score 1):

To reference the resource correctly you need to use the [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) function:

```
Bucket: !Ref WebsiteBucket
```

Two more notes regarding your template:

- You can omit the `DependsOn` section in this case as you are referencing all the resources you are waiting for. When using `Ref`, CloudFormation automatically creates the resources in the correct order (in this case it is Bucket and Access Identity first, Bucket Policy last)
- Instead of using `Join` for combining strings and parameters, you can also use the [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) function which returns referenced values written like `${WebsiteBucket}`, just as `Ref/GetAtt` does.

Template:

```
WebsiteBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref WebsiteBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS:
              Fn::Join: [ ' ', [ 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity', !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity ] ]
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${WebsiteBucket}/*
            # OR:
            # - Fn::Join: [ '', [ 'arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref WebsiteBucket, '/*' ] ]
```